# UIautomator doesn't work .gradlew android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, automated-tests, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to use UIautomator and Espresso to allow location permission on Android Marshmallow and Nougat. I have a simple test that clicks on "Allow" button. It does work when I run it trough android studio, but when I run it trough command line with ./gradlew connectedCheck the test isn't executing. Here's my code:

`@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 18)
public class AllowLocation {`

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

public boolean isFirstTime() {
    if (activityRule.getActivity() != null) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void checkFirstTimeOpen() {
    if (isFirstTime()) {
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.txt_login_cross), withText("X"), isDisplayed()))
                .perform(click());
    }
}

@Test
public void allowLocation() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !isFirstTime()) {
        checkFirstTimeOpen();

       UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
        UiObject allowPermissions = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Allow"));
        if (allowPermissions.exists()) {
            try {
                allowPermissions.click();
                Log.d("Permission clicked", "MainActivity.class");
            } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(e.toString(), "There is no permissions dialog to interact with ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you run tests on emulator check this [tool](https://github.com/linkedin/test-butler). It should help you to handle permission and as a bonus it has some additional stuff on top.